# String.Replace(oldValue, newValue) -- not working

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

Here is my code:

```
//I want to find the oldValue
       string oldValue = "##OfferTitle##";


//In this string:
        stringToReplace = "123##OfferTitle##456";
         string newValue = "Test Offer Title";


//and return it in this variable as "123Test Offer Title456"
        var newString = stringToReplace .Replace(oldValue, newValue );
return newString ;
```

The above is not working. All I get back is the original string.
I expect: "123Test Offer Title456"
But I get stringToReplace ("123##OfferTitle##456") unchanged or unmodified. What am I missing?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It returns the correct string. Could it be that you are checking the value of `stringToReplace` instead? It is not changed, strings are immutable.

Comment: Show the full code where you use this. It should work as expected, but your code is not complete, so we're probably missing something.

Comment: The code works just fine. [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7MSkZt)

Comment: That's not how return works... Do you have actual, compilable code?

Answer (score 2):

Please read the documentation carefully [String.Replace Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns a **new string** in which all occurrences of a specified string in
> the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

Strings are immutable in C#. Original string will stay unchanged.

Comment: "This method does not modify the value of the current instance. Instead, it returns a new string in which all occurrences of oldValue are replaced by newValue." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx ..... So where is the new string that replaced oldValue with newValue? It's still returning my first string.

Comment: @EB. the `Replace` method itself is giving you your new string. The way you're trying to use `return` in your post is just plain wrong.

Comment: @EB. new string is returned by `Replace` method and you immediately returning that value from method without creating temporary variable for new string

Comment: I updated my cod ewith a new variable. Still not getting what i expect. Am I using Replace wrong?

Comment: @EB. no but you are likely using your method wrong. You need to show a complete code example